# Mapped file doesn't take memory on read, but does on write

Tags: c, linux, memory, mmap

I've observed a weird behavior, where a large memory mapped file(2GB), doesn't take actual physical RAM when i read from it, but does when i start writing to it.

```
int err = 0;

int fd = open("large_file", O_RDWR);
if (fd == -1) {
    return errno;
}

void *map = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
                 MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0); 
if (map == MAP_FAILED) {
     err = errno;
     goto out;
}

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 2 << 30; i += PAGE_SIZE) {
      volatile uint8_t val = 0xff;

      // val = ((volatile uint8_t *) map)[i]; /* Doesn't take actual memory */
      // ((volatile uint8_t *) map[i]) = val; /* Takes actual memory */
}

while (1)
    sleep(10);

out:
   if (fd != -1)
      close(fd);
   if (map != MAP_FAILED)
      munmap(map, size);
return err;
```

[This is htop screenshot when i **READ** from the mapped file(look at "check")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlfn9.png)

[This is htop screenshot when i **WRITE** to the mapped file(look at "check"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoPxv.png)

My laptop is pretty much IDLE, nothing else can take physical RAM other than my test process, so you can see when i write to the mapped file it actually takes 2GB(copy-on-write), and when reading, it doesn't. RES-SHR also fits in both of my cases.

I can't explain it.. the kernel maps a new page regardless if it's a read or a write to physical RAM. If it wasn't present, it should be mapped and take actual RAM after a page fault exception. The mapped file is **not** mapped to other processes, so it isn't shared. The test process is the only one and the first one that maps the file into memory.

EDIT:
I've added the (volatile) keyword to make sure the compiler doesn't optimize the critical code. This doesn't make any difference. This particular piece of assembly code is the output of reading from the memory mapped file:

```
mov    BYTE PTR [rbp-0xbd],0xff /* volatile uint8_t val = 0xff; */
mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rbp-0xbc] 
mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0xb0]
add    rax,rdx
movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [rax]     
mov    BYTE PTR [rbp-0xbd],al   /* val = ((volatile uint8_t *)map)[i]; */
add    DWORD PTR [rbp-0xbc],0x1000 /* i += PAGE_SIZE; */
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I suppose this is what happens: if you read without ever having written, the values you read are meaningless anyway so the kernel doesn't bother to map any physical memory.

Comment: Isn't that that disk cache is used using COW?

Comment: @Jabberwocky This doesn't make any sense. The kernel has no knowledge on whether i'm using a value or not. If i'm reading a value, it assumes i need it, so it maps physical page to that virtual address.

Comment: @MikeBazov it's not about the kernel not knowing what you do with the value you've read (it's true it doesn't know that you're doing nothing with it). It's about reading uninitialized memory which is pointless. BTW what values do you get when you read from `map`? Does the file exist beforehand?

Comment: @Jabberwocky The file is filled with ascii characters. I get values i expect when i print "val". I don't see your point.. what memory isn't initialized? and yes, the file does exist.

Comment: Can you show the htop output when your program does just the mmap, and no reads and no writes?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your compiler just optimizes the read accesses. It can do so, since you never do anything with it. Easiest would be to change the declaration of `val`:

```
uint8_t volatile val = ... ;
```

but you could also declare `map` accordingly:

```
uint8_t volatile*map = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
             MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
```

(Declaring the sought type for `map` also avoids to have the nasty cast later on.)

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, so it seems. The compiler didn't optimize this particular piece of code, and i have added the "volatile" keyword just to make sure. See my edit.